# What would have happened if the strong coupling constant were a bit higher or a bit weaker?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, physical-constants

I encountered it was anoounced:
If the strong force constant were 5% weaker, there would be no stable stars
If the strong force constant were 2% stronger, there would be no stable hydrogen, no long-lived stars, no hydrogen containing compounds

I would like someone gives any link(s) to underpin these by really calculations

Comment: could you give a link of where you read this statement?

Comment: I am familiar with the paper of Uzan, (The fundamental constants and their variation: observational status and theoretical motivations, arXiv:hep-ph/0205340v1 30 May 2002) and with the mentioned by you article, http://www.focus.org.uk/strongforce_long.pdf). Sorry, I could not find neither in the paper nor in the article the concrete numbers 5% and 2 % mentioned in my question and what I have find on the Stack exchange in the answer to the question "What is the best explanation for the fine tuning of the Universe? [closed]". I could find in Uzan's paper only a lot of calculations.

Comment: your comment was conveyed to me, instead of  @Zachos, whom I alerted now.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is that nuclear physics, and  hence  cosmic nucleosynthesis, relies on very delicately balanced electromagnetic, weak, and strong force thresholds, and so a small variation of the strong binding forces would upend the normal nuclear stability conditions on which nuclei form or fail to.
The solid review article written for scientists, [Uzan, J. P. (2003) "The fundamental constants and their variation: observational and theoretical status"  *Rev mod phys* **75** (2), 403](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.75.403), has all you need in section V.B.

I would not wish to appear actually endorsing the rabbit hole of these anthropic principle speculations, but here is an overview [article](http://www.focus.org.uk/strongforce_long.pdf) that gives you a glimpse of the "why"...

The mother of these speculations might be

- Barrow, J D and Tipler, F J, *The Anthropic Cosmological Principle* , Oxford University Press 1988, [ISBN-13 : 978-0192821478](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0192821474),

or

- Rees, M, *Just Six Numbers: the deep forces that shape the universe* , Basic Books, 2000  [ISBN-13 : 978-0465036738](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465036732)

Caveat Lector.

Comment: Well, I have not followed every twist and turn of the methodologies employed; there have been *hundreds* of papers on the subject. I certainly do not know how these *precise* numbers come up... *that* question should reference them. Be advised that popular science articles on the subject are criminally unscrupulous, and feel entitled to throw around numbers without backup, and the closed question OP appears flakey. Are you *positive* no papers citing Uzan have such numbers?

Comment: I have foud these precise numbers on the Stack exchange in the answer to the question "What is the best explanation for the fine tuning of the Universe? [closed]".